# HTTP 403 when downloading images from a .CSV file with URL's What can I do?

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-403, http-error

```
def url_to_jpg(i, url, FILE_PATH):
try:
    url_basename = url.split("/")[-1]
    filename = '{}.jpg'.format(url_basename.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ])
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(FILE_PATH, filename)
    response = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
    print('{} saved.'.format(full_path))
    return None
except HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

That's the central part of my code, without the elements and stuff, what can I do to be able to avoid that 403 error, maybe trying selenium?

Comment: You probably have to authorize before you can download those images. 403 means Forbidden.  The server understood your request but refused it because you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: @Jeff It's for a Scrapping project at work, I don't have any authorization, that's why I need to find a way to skip that. Here's 1 URL : https://www.bananarepublic.com.pe/media/catalog/product/cache/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/b/r/br493497_b09_1.jpg

Comment: I have no trouble downloading this image with `requests`.

Comment: Have you tried changing the User-Agent request header?

Answer (score 0):

```
def url_to_jpg(i, url, filepath):
url_basename = url.split("/")[-1]
imagename = '{}.jpg'.format(url_basename.rsplit( ".", 1 )[0])
fullpath = '{}{}'.format(filepath, imagename)
response = requests.get(url, fullpath)
file = open(imagename, "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
print('{} saved.'.format(fullpath))
return None
filename = 'libro.csv'
```

filepath = 'fotospython/'
urls = pd.read_csv(filename)

for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):
url_to_jpg(i, url[0], filepath)

that was my final requests using code, it works, but can't put the files in the folder, nowadays, worked